# how to iterate Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>>> in java?

Tags: java, collections

I  have a method which is returning  `Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>>>`

How to iterate over a map like `Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>>>`

Comment: Probably this is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898/how-to-efficiently-iterate-over-each-entry-in-a-map#46908

Comment: What do you need to do while iterating over this map?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: There is  List<Map<String,Object>> inside of Map.There I am Confusing to iterate

Comment: Someone's trying to help you. Mindless repeating your question doesn't help anyone.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing confusing about it. Iterate over the map as usual. If you wish to iterate over the inner list, do that, if you want to iterate over the nested map again, do it - just nest your basic iterations.

Answer (score 4):

You would iterate over it like you would iterate over every other map. You just need to "recursively" iterate over the List and another Aap inside the iteration loop.

One possible way (without functional code):

```
Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>>> yourMap = ...;
//iterate over outer map
for(Map.Entry<String, List<Map<String, Object>>> topEntry : yourMap.entrySet()) {
  String topKey = topEntry.getKey();
  //iterate over list
  for(Map<String, Object> innerMap : topEntry.getValue()) {
    //iterate over inner map
    for(Map.Entry<String, Object> innerEntry : innerMap.entrySet()) {
      String innerKey = innerEntry.getKey();
      Object innerValue = innerEntry.getValue();
    }
  }
}
```

You can also switch the foreach loop iterating over the List to a fori loop [ `for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)` ] if you need to know the list-index.

Comment: And what is that error? did you define the map or is it just null?